# Error installing nginx with passenger-install-nginx-module on ubuntu 11.10 & rails 3.1.0

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Here is the error message from installing nginx with passenger-install- nginx-module (rvmsudo). The nginx is 1.0.6 installed under /opt/nginx (default). gem install passenger successfully prior.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/dtt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.9/
ext/nginx/../common/libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o): undefined
reference to symbol 'round@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'round@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/
x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so so try adding
it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so:
could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/root-passenger-2135/nginx-1.0.6'
make: *** [build] Error 2
--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/OW-NDvlWLno

```
 hey! I solve this issue moving block:

 ngx_feature="Math library" ngx_feature_name= ngx_feature_run=no
 ngx_feature_incs="#include <math.h>" ngx_feature_path=
 ngx_feature_libs="-lm" ngx_feature_test="pow(1, 2)"  . auto/feature if
 [ $ngx_found = yes ]; then
     CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS -lm" fi

 to after:

 ngx_addon_name=ngx_http_passenger_module HTTP_MODULES="$HTTP_MODULES
 ngx_http_passenger_module" NGX_ADDON_SRCS="$NGX_ADDON_SRCS \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ngx_http_passenger_module.c \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/Configuration.c \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ContentHandler.c \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/StaticContentHandler.c" NGX_ADDON_DEPS="$NGX_ADDON_DEPS \   
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/Configuration.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ContentHandler.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/StaticContentHandler.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/ngx_http_passenger_module.h \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/../common/Constants.h" CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS  \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/../common/libpassenger_common.a \
     ${ngx_addon_dir}/../common/libboost_oxt.a \
     -lstdc++ -lpthread"

 in ext/nginx/config
```